# Print objects that are not of type string from the list

Tags: python

I am trying to create an array with some objects of type SVC. I get the message displayed below. I tried different approach, and also using `np.array([svc_lin, svc_poly, svc_sig])` (where np is `numpy`), which gives a similar error.

Is there a way to do what I am trying with these kind of objects (maybe another suitable array? I am completely new to python, so I know not much

Thanks for any help.

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC

svc_lin = SVC(kernel='linear')
svc_poly = SVC(kernel='poly')
svc_sig = SVC(kernel='sigmoid')

arL = [svc_lin, svc_poly, svc_sig]

for x in arL: 
    #start=time.time()
    print(arL[x])
```

Error message I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not SVC
```

Comment: Don't you just want `print(x)`? `x` is not an index into your sequence, it is the object/element itself

Comment: If you loop as `for x in l`, then `x` are already the elements. If you loop with `for i in range(len(l))` then `i` is the index and you then need to do `l[i]`

Comment: You are right guys. That was the problem. I was thinking that I needed to print what was at that index. I have much to learn yet. Thanks

Comment: @Tomerikoo - please don't suggest `range(len( ... ))` for indices.  It's considerably more pythonic to use `for idx, elem in enumerate( ... )` if you need the indices for some reason.

Comment: @g.d.d.c I didn't really understand what you said there. I actually did use range(len) as he suggested, as it was better than my first solution. Can you explain, maybe with an example why this is not good?

Comment: @user1960836 - the main problem with `for i in range(len( ... ))` is that it only supports collections of known length.  That means it is _broken_ for generators.  It also requires you to make an extra lookup into your collection for each iteration (the `l[i]` line). This lookup is unnecessary when you use `for idx, elem in enumerate( ... )` because `idx` and `elem` are assigned to the index and corresponding object _already_.  It's cleaner, more concise, and supports more collection types.

Comment: @g.d.d.c I didn't suggest. I tried to show the difference because OP was using `arL[x]`. So that is used with `for range...`. But I would definitely suggest to go with simple `for x in l` loops or maybe use `enumerate`...